# Dependency injection vs Factory or Directory

Tags: spring, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

I have been wondering if anyone uses DI/IoC in any non-toy project, where he can choose the implementation style (rather than this being enforced by libraries or development requirements).

After all, a Factory is just the perfect mechanism if we want a single instance of a class, and a Directory service is the perfect mechanism if we want *a* specific instance.

So what is the big deal with adding Spring/Guice/etc. into this and creating another dependency for ourselves? (Or maybe I completely fail to understand their DI approach...)

Thanks.

Comment: DI will also help you with lifecycle management, and will allow you to get closer to _declaring_ your dependencies instead of manually acquiring them. That said, I can see nothing wrong with the patterns you describe if you're more comfortable with them.

Comment: Testability is the main advantage of DI: you can inject mock dependencies in unit tests. I would say that now, almost all non-toy Java projects use DI: Spring promotes DI, Java EE with CDI promotes DI. Read http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Motivation?tm=6 for the motivation of DI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DI (Dependency Inversion) principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) says nothing about frameworks and simply claims that:

> 1. High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.
> 2. Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions.

Inversion of control (IoC) principle is also related to decreasing coupling among classes in your software.

There are many patterns that are used to keep your classes low coupled and follow DI or IoC principle. It is you responsibility how to meet this goal. [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) are some of them.

> After all, a Factory is just the perfect mechanism if we want a single instance of a class, and a Directory service is the perfect mechanism if we want a specific instance.

And Factory is considered as one of the [implementation techniques of inversion of comtrol principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control#Implementation_techniques).

> I have been wondering if anyone uses DI/IoC in any non-toy project, where he can choose the implementation style (rather than this being enforced by libraries or development requirements).

I see lots of enterprise applications where DI\IoC containers\frameworks are used. These frameworks provide an infrastructure that cares about object creation (like [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern)), its lifetime (like [Singleton](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx)), injecting dependencies, holding a list of all objects (like [Registry](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html))

> So what is the big deal with adding Spring/Guice/etc. into this and creating another dependency for ourselves?

Your classes have no dependencies on any IoC container when you use it. **IoC container is a part of your infrastucture layer only.**

I think, the only one reason to avoid usage of IoC container is when you are restricted to use 3rd party libraries by company's rules and agreements.

Comment: ... And thank you again! Those links were very useful!